# Python primitive types comparison v/s object comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

What is the basic difference between **Primitive Type comparison** and **Object comparison**

I want to compare two dates and it's easily done by primitive types then why should I create object for that and compare objects ?

```
import datetime
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
d = '2015-10-23'
e = '2015-10-23'
d == e ==> True

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,fmt)
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(e,fmt)
d1 == d2 ==> True

d = '2015-10-03'
e = '2015-10-04'
d > e ==> False
e > d ==> True
```

if primitive types working fine then why we need to create object for that ?

Which one is better to use ?

Comment: If your dates are in the same sensible format, then string comparison (and even lexicographical ordering) will work fine, but *what if they're not*? And what if you want to e.g. subtract the two to find out the `timedelta` between them; good luck doing that with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive type comparison might lead to false result answer when there is date in not sensible format.

E.g

```
d = '2015-33-03'
e = '2015-32-32'
print(d > e) 
print(e > d)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you have listed is called the `isoformat`.

You can see this by calling `dateObj.isoformat()`.

In ISO format(yyyy-mm-dd), you are really comparing the string equivalent of the date, which so happens to give you the same result as the string comparison would give...and there is nothing wrong in using that.

Comparing date directly with its counterpart would probably be considered "safer" b/c it's possible that you provide incompatible string formats and get wrong results (example: comparing 2015-10-01 with 2015-19-01).

Lastly, to answer your generic question on object comparison, for your own custom object you need to define a proper `__hash__` and `__eq__` functions. Also google: python's `functools.total_ordering` for more savvy comparison stuff on custom objects

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html